# Upload shapefile and download raster layer for area GEE apps?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

My Google Earth Engine app allows you to select a raster layer and then download that layer as a zip containing a tif. Here is the javascript code in the GEE IDE for the downloading part:

```
function downloadImg() {
  var viewBounds = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(Map.getBounds()); // CHANGE BOUNDARIES TO SHAPEFILE
  var downloadArgs = {
    name: 'sample_image',
    crs: 'EPSG:4326',
    region: viewBounds.toGeoJSONString()
 };

 var img = imgCol.first(); 

 var url =img.getDownloadURL(downloadArgs);
 urlLabel.setUrl(url);
 urlLabel.style().set({shown: true});
}

// Add UI elements to the Map.
var downloadButton = ui.Button('Get download link', downloadImg);
var urlLabel = ui.Label('Download', {shown: false});
var buttons = ui.Panel([downloadButton, urlLabel]);
c.controlPanel.add(buttons);
```

This protoype just auto-selects the first layer in my ImageCollection right now.

I want to add widgets to allow the user to upload a shapefile and only download the raster data within that shapefile. It would also be great to be able to draw a polygon and download that shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps can't do upload and can only do download through getDownloadUrl or getThumbnail.

Comment: I was hoping this wouldn't be the case. Do you know if something similar is achievable through other means? I'm trying to achieve something like this: https://rangelands.app/rap/